# Assuming uniqueness in Peano Theorem for ODEs, show that the sequence of approximate solutions is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

If we know existence of solutions for
$$
x'=f(t,x), \quad x(t_0)=x_0,
$$
obtained by Peano's Theorem, and furthermore we know that the solution in unique ( we have not assumed satisfaction of Lipschitz condition by $f$).

How we can proof that the sequence in Peano's Theorem is converging uniformly ( in the proof of Peano's Theorem, by the help of Arzela-Ascoli theorem we only have at least a subsequence converging uniformly and not every subsequence).

I think that if I be able to show that the sequence is cauchy sequence and since we have a subsequence convergent, then every subsequence will be convergent. but I can't use the uniqueness to show chauchyness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence of approximate solutions $v_n:I\to\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb R^n$) constructed by Peano method possesses a uniformly convergent subsequence (due to Arzela-Ascoli as $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous), and the limit can only be the UNIQUE solution $v$ of the underlying IVP. This is also true for every subsequence of $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ for the same reason.

Using the following fact:

*If every subsequence of a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$
possesses a sub-subsequence converging to $f$, then $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ also
converges to $f$.*

we obtain that the whole $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $v$.

Comment: One detail: The fact is known as the **subsequence principle** and the proof is easy: If $f_n \not\to f$, then for some $\epsilon > 0$, we have $\Vert f_n - f\Vert_\sup \geq \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n\in\Bbb{N}$ (negate the def. of convergence). Hence, there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ with $\Vert f_{n_k} - f\Vert \geq \epsilon$ for all $k$. By assumption, some subsequence of $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f$, contradiction. One should not that it is important to **fix** the limit $f$. It is not true that $f_n$ converges iff every subsequence of $f_n$ has a sub-subsequence which converges.